# Can I new-game-plus Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel with a different character?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Once completed the game, you are offered to re-play it in new-game-plus mode, that is, keeping your stuff, level and perks. The increased challenge of having tougher enemies around makes it a new experience.

However, I'd like to try a different character (e.g. Fragtrap instead of Athena). Is there a way to do it? Maybe with console commands?

Answer (score 4):

Nop. You have to start from 0 with another character to be able to play in: "new-game-plus mode"

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are save-game editors that would allow you to take a newly-created character and change their level, inventory, and story progression so that they'd be on the second playthrough.

However, I wouldn't recommend it - you'd be playing against harder enemies with a character that you were less used to.

If you just want to pass along stuff, I seem to recall there being a stash in town that'll let you pass a small number of items between characters, so that will give your new character a bit of a leg up.

Comment: I was thinking of raising the level with cheats, but that would probably not raise the levels of the enemies, rendering everything entirely trivial. Hence, the question.

Comment: @bitmask - Enemy levels are dependent on your character's level, I believe - each area will spawn enemies with levels between a certain range, and as your level goes up, they'll move towards the top of that range. I'll see if I can find a citation.

Comment: I thought Borderlands has fixed levels. That's why some missions are extremely trivial if chosen late in the game. But I'm not sure how this works. Maybe this should be a distinct question ...

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/324314/10310

Comment: There is no level range, enemy levels are fixed though there can be a few different levels of enemies in one area(badasses tend to be a couple of level higher than their surrounding mobs), but if you see a level 10 scav in that place he'll still be lvl 10 no matter your level or how many times he respawn. This only changes in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode where all enemies scales to the players level.